# VueJS add external site to router history

Tags: vue.js, jwt, query-string

I am building an app using Vue Router that uses an "external" site for login credentials.  It essentially looks like this:

```
Home.Vue

<template>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Home",
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    created() {
      window.location = 'https://third_party_site.com?nextpage=http://my_site.com/#/entry'
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

This third_party_site.com handles auth and sends a JWT back as a query string in the resulting URL.  When I try to use a navigation guard (as shown below) to get the query string, Vue router only looks in the router's history.

```
router/index.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import Entry from '@/components/Entry'
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/entry',
      name: 'Entry',
      component: Entry,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        console.log('to',to)
        console.log('from',from)
        console.log('next',next)
        next()
      },
      meta: {
        title: 'Entry'
      }
    },
  ]
})
```

The console prints the expected "to" location but the "from" location is the base path, "/", and there are no query parameters.  How do I go about getting the "external" route so I can access the query parameters?  The resulting console.log of "from" is below.

```
from 
  {name: null, meta: {…}, path: "/", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
    fullPath: "/"
    hash: ""
    matched: []
    meta: {}
    name: null
    params: {}
    path: "/"
    query: {}
    __proto__: Object
```

Before asking, the app, in its current state, has to be built this way and I do not have access to the external site.

Comment: Are you saying the remote site isn't adding a query parameter to your `/entry` URL when it comes back to your site?

Comment: I notice you're not using HTML5 history mode in your router so shouldn't the `nextpage` URL be something like `http://my_site.com/#/entry`?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying is happening, Phil.  Whether it is added after /entry or it is available in "from" in the navigation guard matters little.  I simply need access to it at some point in time.

Your comment was also correct about the hash; that was a typo when I formatted the question but it is included in the window.location url in Home.vue

Comment: Use your browser's _Network_ console and check the _"Preserve log"_ option. Follow the requests as you navigate through authentication and see if... a) The remote site is or is not including the correct query parameter, and b) if it is, what happens to it

Answer (score 0):

Wild shot in the dark here but the `#` in your `nextpage` query parameter is probably messing with the remote site.

What it will see is

```
QUERY    => nextpage=http://my_site.com/
FRAGMENT => #/entry
```

so it will redirect back to `http://my_site.com/` because it probably ignores any fragment.

You should encode the value correctly, eg

```js
window.location = 'https://third_party_site.com/?nextpage=' + 
    encodeURIComponent('http://my_site.com/#/entry')
```

which will produce `nextpage=http%3A%2F%2Fmy_site.com%2F%23%2Fentry`

Comment: That actually returns a 400 "invalid URL" response.  It shows the external URL in the address bar (with the token I need) but does not redirect to the needed page.

Comment: Is the 400 from your server or theirs? You might need to start adding some request / response information to your question

Comment: Perhaps this remote service can't handle `#` URLs. Any chance you can enable [HTML5 History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)? Note: it does require some server-configuration

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of (using Vue router to try to push the external link, enabling history mode, etc.) and nothing is working.  What sort of request/response information are you referring to that would be needed?

Comment: See my comment above about the browser Network console. Also, maybe you missed my question about where the 400 comes from

Comment: You're correct, I did miss that. I don't see the query string anywhere in the log so I'm going to have to meet with the person who created the redirect route to see how it's being appended